# For which real numbers $x$ is $\arcsin(2x^2-1)-2\arcsin x=-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\arcsin(2x^2-1)-2\arcsin x=-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: The title isn't supposed to be the first line of your question.

Comment: For any $x$ which makes sense the following is true:
$$\begin{align} \arcsin (2x^2-1)-2\arcsin (x)=-\dfrac \pi 2&\iff \arcsin (2x^2-1)=2\arcsin (x)-\dfrac \pi 2 \\
&\implies \sin(\arcsin (2x^2-1))=\sin \left(2\arcsin (x)-\dfrac \pi 2\right)\\
&\implies 2x^2-1 =\cos (2\arcsin(x))\\
&\implies 2x^2-1=(\cos(\arcsin (x)))^2-(\sin (\arcsin(x)))^2\\
&\implies 2x^2-1=\pm\sqrt{1-(\sin (\arcsin(x)))^2}-x^2\\
&\implies 2x^2-1=\pm \sqrt{1-x^2} -x^2\\
&\,\,\,\,\,\vdots\end{align}$$
**Warning:** I didn't check to see if it's easy to do the rest.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\arccos x=y\iff x=\cos y$ where $0\le y\le \pi$ which is the [range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) of the principal values of $\arccos x$

$\implies 0\le2y\le2\pi$

as $\arccos x+\arcsin x=\frac\pi2$

$\displaystyle\arcsin(2x^2-1)-2\arcsin x$

$\displaystyle=\arcsin(2\cos^2y-1)-2\left(\frac\pi2-y\right)$

$\displaystyle=\arcsin(\cos2y)-\pi+2y$

$\displaystyle=\frac\pi2-\arccos(\cos2y)-\pi+2y$

**Case** $1:\arccos(\cos2y)=2y \iff 0\le 2y\le\pi\iff0\le y\le\frac\pi2$

**Case** $2:$ else we have $\frac\pi2<y\le\pi,$  consequently $\arccos(\cos2y)=2\pi-2y$